# sum elements of list under conditions of second list

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I'm trying to add up certain elements of two lists that are related. I will put an example so you understand what I'm talking about. In the end I write the code I have, it works but I want to optimize it, otherwise I have to write lots of things by hand. Apologies if the question is not interesting.

```
list1 = [4.0, 8.0, 14.0, 20.0, 22.0, 26.0, 28.0, 30.0, 32.0, 34.0, 36.0, 38.0, 40.0]
list2 = [2.1, 1.8, 9.5, 5., 5.4, 6.7, 3.3, 5.3, 8.8, 9.4, 5., 9.3, 3.1]
```

List 1 corresponds to time, so what I want to do is to cluster everything every 10 [units of time], i.e. from list1 I can see that the first and second element belong to the range 0-10, so I would need to add their corresponding points in list2. Later from list1 I see that the third and fourth elements belong to the range (10< time <= 20), so I add the same elements in list2, later for the third range, I need to add the following 4 elements in list3 and so on. In the end I would like to create 2 new lists

```
list3 = [10., 20., 30., 40.]
list4 = [3.9, 14.5, 20.7, 35.6]
```

The code I wrote is the following:

```
list1 = [4.0, 8.0, 14.0, 20.0, 22.0, 26.0, 28.0, 30.0, 32.0, 34.0, 36.0, 38.0, 40.0]
list2 = [2.1, 1.8, 9.5, 5., 5.4, 6.7, 3.3, 5.3, 8.8, 9.4, 5., 9.3, 3.1]
list3 = numpy.arange(0., 40., 10.)
a = [[] for i in range(4)]

for i, j in enumerate(list1):
    if 0.<=j<=10.:
        a[0].append(list2[i])
    elif 10.<j<=20.:
        a[1].append(list2[i])
    elif 20.<j<=30.:
        a[2].append(list2[i])
    elif 30.<j<=40.:
        a[3].append(list2[i])

list4 = [sum(i) for i in a]
```

it works, however, list1 in reality is way more larger (few orders of magnitude) and I don't want to write all the if's by hand (as well as the sublists I make). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the numbers will be ascending in `list1`?

Comment: Hi, yes, however they are not ascending in a linear way, it's mainly random. list1 basically represents an increase in time.

Comment: that's not a problem. But it is guaranteed that the next element is always larger than the previous one?

Comment: Yes. They are sorted in that way.

Comment: What if you don't have a sample for a period of time larger than 10 units of time? Should you put 0 in the list4 in that case?

Comment: Yes, the two lists are related, basically list2 is a function of list1, so it could be zero if there's no data for a range of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if we are talking about *huge* sets, I would use `numpy`, `pandas`, or another tool that is designed for this. From my experience, Python itself is not designed to work for things with more than 10M elements (unless there is a structure in the data you can exploit).

Now we can use this as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# construct lists
l1 = np.array(list1)
l2 = np.array(list2)

# determine the "groups" of the values
g = (l1-0.00001)//10

# create a boolean mask that determines where the groups change
flag = np.concatenate(([True], g[1:] != g[:-1]))

# determine the indices of the swaps
inv_idx, = flag.nonzero()

# calculate the sum per subrange
result = np.add.reduceat(list2,inv_idx)
```

For your sample output, this gives:

```
>>> result
array([  3.9,  14.5,  20.7,  35.6])
```

The `0.00001` is used to push a `20.0` to some `19.9999` is and thus assign it to group 1 instead of group 2. The advantage of this approach is that (a) it works for an arbitrary number of "groups" and (b) a fixed number of "swipes" are done over the list so it scales linear with the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work for a small example. I'll try my largest one. I would have never come up with something like this myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you transform your list in numpy.array, there are easy way to extract some stuff in a 1D-array based on another one:

```
import numpy
list1 = numpy.array([4.0, 8.0, 14.0, 20.0, 22.0, 26.0, 28.0, 30.0, 32.0, 34.0, 36.0, 38.0, 40.0])
list2 = numpy.array([2.1, 1.8, 9.5, 5., 5.4, 6.7, 3.3, 5.3, 8.8, 9.4, 5., 9.3, 3.1])

step = 10
r, s = range(0,50,10), []
for i in r:
    s.append(numpy.sum([l for l in list2[(list1 > i) & (list1 <= i+step)]]))
print r[1:], s[:-1]
#[10, 20, 30, 40] [3.9, 14.5, 20.7, 35.6]
```

**Edit**
In one line:

```
s = [numpy.sum([l for l in list2[(list1 > i) & (list1 < i+step)]]) for i in r]
```